# How to use properly loadHtmlFile() in php?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to load an html file using the loadHTMLFile() but it doesn't work properly. Everytime it add this text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
```

Anytime i run this code that text is added

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('file.html');
$content = html_entity_decode($dom->saveXML());
$n = file_put_contents($file, $content) or die('file not found');  // write the contents back to the file
echo html_entity_decode($dom->saveXML());
```

My aim is to load a document, make some changes and then save it without the 2 code lines. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please tell me the location of  "file.html"? Try absolute path for your file. Please provide more error info/trace.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the DOMDocument class, but I'm guessing this has something to do with it: `$dom->saveXML()`. Anyway, why is it a problem? The `<!DOCTYPE>` tag, especially, should be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load with the additional [`LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD`](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php#constant.libxml-html-nodefdtd) option which prevents a default doctype being added when one is not found *(available in Libxml >= 2.7.8 as of PHP >= 5.4.0)* and use either [`saveHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) or [`C14N()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.c14n.php) instead of `saveXML()` to avoid the xml declaration.

e.g.:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('file.html', LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
echo $dom->C14N();
```